# Time column in mysql table

Tags: python, mysql, sql, field, sqldatatypes

I want to store a time value in a mysql table,

```
1345:55
```

it is 1345 hours and 55 minutes. What type should column have?

And if I want to pass a time variable from python to this column using `mysqldb` module, which time type should i use in python? `datetime.timedelta`?

Comment: What range of values do you need to support?

Comment: What level of granularity do you require?  Minutes?  Seconds?  Milliseconds?  Microseconds?

Comment: Minutes is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, one can use MySQL's [`TIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/time.html) datatype to store time values:

> MySQL retrieves and displays `TIME` values in `'HH:MM:SS'` format (or `'HHH:MM:SS'` format for large hours values). `TIME` values may range from `'-838:59:59'` to `'838:59:59'`.

Obviously, in your case, this is insufficient for the range of values required.  I would therefore suggest that you instead convert the value to an integer number of minutes and store the result in an 4-byte `INT UNSIGNED` column (capable of storing values in the range 0 to 4294967295, representing 0:00 to 71582788:15).

Comment: Thanks, which python datatype should I use when writing if "843:45" (843 hours and 45 minutes) to this field?

Comment: @alwbtc: I don't know much about Python, but [`timedelta`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) looks promising.